# Getting all classes with certain class name followed by a digit

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example a class called `movelist_1`, `movelist_2`, how do I grab all movelist classes followed by a underscore and a number?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('*[class^="movelist_"]')` ?

Comment: @Matias Cicero didn't work

Comment: What exactly do you mean by didn't work? Please, be specific. Show example code with actual input and expected output. If you are getting any errors, please provide them.

Comment: @MatiasCicero `class="movelist_not_a_number"` will be grabbed too...

Comment: @MatiasCicero I think the `*` is useless.

Comment: @dhilt Well, this is a close as we can get with CSS selectors, as regexes are not supported yet. You can always query explicitly for the 9 classes.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You're right, just confirmed it

Comment: I added the answer with approach that satisfies "numeric" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's say we have

```
<h1 class="my_1">Hello 1</h1>
<h1 class="my_2">Hello 2</h1>
<h1 class="my_3">Hello 3</h1>
<h1 class="my_NaN">Hello NaN</h1>
<h1 class="not_my">No Hello</h1>
```

To obtain "my_" + a number elements I would use a combination of `querySelectorAll` (to get elements with classes started with "my_") and manual regexp parsing (to filter non-numeric cases):

```
function getMyElements() {
  var result = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=my_]"); // just started with "my_"

  var _result = [];
  for(var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(var j = result[i].classList.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if(result[i].classList[j].search(/my_\d/i) === 0) { // started with "my_" + digit
         _result.push(result[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return _result; 
}

console.log(getMyElements()); // (3) [h1.my_3, h1.my_2, h1.my_1]
```

The inner loop is needed to handle a situation when multiple classes are assigned to the element.

Answer (score 0):

You get them all with [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). The result is a `NodeList`. Go through the `NodeList` with

`[].forEach.call();`

```js
// For example get all innerHTML

var res = [];
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class^=movelist_]"), m => {
  res.push(m.innerHTML);
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="movelist_1">Move 1</div>
<div class="movelist_2">Move 2</div>
<div class="movelist_3">Move 3</div>
<div class="movelist_4">Move 4</div>
<div class="movelist_5">Move 5</div>
```